# Serialize object to JSON without a root key in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I use Jackson to serialize objects in Java. I build an object and now I would like to get a "rootless" JSON like:

```
{
    "requestHeader": {
       "specVersion":"1.2",
       "customerId":"123123"
     },
     "someThingElse": "123"
}
```

Here, `requestHeader` and `someThingElse` are on the same root level.

Using this code, I am forced to set a key:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
...
ObjectNode response = mapper.createObjectNode();
response.set("unwantedRootKey", data);
```

Which results in an extra root level which i don't want.

```
{
    "unwantedRootKey": {
          "requestHeader": {
              "specVersion":"1.2",
              "customerId":"123123"
          },
          "someThingElse": "123"
    }
}
```

How can I add the data in a serial way, thus not creating a tree but a forest so to speak? (I could chop the final string but well...)

Comment: `response.set('requestheader', data.requestheader); response.set('somethingelse', '123)`?

Comment: @raolsson Did not understand the question correctly. I will be able to answer the question if you can tell me why are you doing response.set("unwantedRootKey", data) ?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem you are experiencing, using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode()` would be a much more direct way of creating a new ObjectNode reference to work on instead of going through ObjectMapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Marc B, I tried the obvious: Simply set multiple entries into the root level:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode response = mapper.createObjectNode();
response.set("requestHeader", mapper.valueToTree(data.getRequestHeader()));
response.set("someThingElse", mapper.valueToTree(data.getSomethingElse()));
```

I was too sleepy today and missed the forest for only seeing the tree...